# Multiple APIs and XML resources

Tags: android, xml

I know this is probably a simple question. Though, I could not find the answer anywhere. I have some XML elements that are available for v21+ APIs. Something like:

```
<item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
```

Which is part of the styles.xml. Should I go ahead and create a new styles.xml v21 file with only

```
<style name="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
</style>
```

or I need to clone the styles.xml file and add that line. Maybe I could keep the line into the main file and count on it being ignored by old systems?

I would appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Jack, you could only use the new `styles.xml` v21 file with only changes specific to the v21 and above versions. For all other information which is not available in the `styles.xml` v21 file, the system uses the default `styles.xml` to look up for the values. So, you need not clone the file.

Hope this answers the question.

Comment: So, on a v19 system the styles.xml file is read only. While on v21 systems both files are read with all the values on both styles.xml files?

Comment: No both cannot be read simultaneously. If you have any style property on a specific version that gets picked. If the property is not found on that version, the system checks the same property on a lower version and so on. In not found anywhere, it takes the default value from `styles.xml`.